# SELECT DISTINCT is too slow, how do I use a PHP array instead?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large database and even with indexes it's slowing down a lot when I use `SELECT DISTINCT`. I thought I'd change it to use an array instead but somehow it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

The original code is:

```
$product_countries = $this->query("SELECT DISTINCT country FROM db_products");

        $listing_countries = array();
        while ($listing_details = $this->fetch_array($product_countries)){
            if (!empty($listing_details['country'])){
            $listing_countries[] = $listing_details['country'];
            }
        }
```

Now, I tried changing it to:

```
// $product_countries = $this->query("SELECT DISTINCT country FROM db_products");
   $product_countries = array("2084", "1993");
```

And the `while` part to:

```
while ($listing_details = $product_countries){
```

But that's not working. What am I doing wrong here? I'm pretty sure it's somewhere in that while line and the fact that the before it used a mySQL resource and then afterwards I changed it to an array, but I can't figure it out :(

Comment: When you search with no Where clause if I am not mistaken you are doing  a full table scan anyway and the indexes don't really play a big part of that.  The better question is why do you need them distinct? Would it be better to separate the duplicate data into a table and use a join with a foreign key for it?  Your `mysqli` in this case looks fine from what there is of it.  How many rows of data do you have?  What is Large, I have a table with 700+ records, that's large to me.

Comment: ^700K as in 700,000, records. Not 700 :)

Comment: DISTINCTs generally *are* slow. As a rule, if you find yourself using a DISTINCT, question whether there's something wrong with either your query, or your database design. On occasion they are necessary, but it should be pretty infrequently. @ArtisiticPhoenix is spot on in saying it would be better to split the country data out into a separate table if it isn't already. Sorting out the problem in your front end logic isn't going to fix the performance problem in the long term (and it may get worse), and won't help other queries which use the same data.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah - assignment is intentional in this case.

Comment: If one ever thinks php loop is going to do it faster, I say put down the koolaid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
  $product_countries = array("2084", "1993");
```

There's no need for a `while` loop. Just get the contents of that array assigned to another array. Like this:

```
  $product_countries = array("2084", "1993");
  $listing_details = $product_countries;
```

And be done with it.  (You already know that the values in the $product_countries array are already defined, and aren't going to evaluate to FALSE, so there's no need for any conditional test.

With the `while` loop as you show, how will that ever exit? Looks like a classic infinite loop to me.

---

If that's not the question you are asking...

As far as the MySQL query goes, the only appropriate index for the query would be a BTREE index (not a HASH index) with a leading column of `country`.  Ideally (for this query) on just that single column:

```
 ... ON db_products(country)
```

The query should be equivalent to a GROUP BY query:

```
 SELECT country FROM db_products GROUP BY country
```

I recommend you run an `EXPLAIN` on the query to verify that it's using an index and not doing a "Using filesort" operation. (This assumes that `db_products` is a table, and not some harebrained view definition.)

I'm not understanding why the conditional test on the return of the `empty` function is needed. If `fetch_array` returned a row, then variable is going to be defined, so that test really only checking if the value returned from the database evaluates to `FALSE`. If I wanted to exclude values of `country` that evaluate to FALSE, I would tend to include the appropriate predicate in the query definition.

Comment: `Looks like a classic infinite loop to me.`  How as that, looks like a classic database result building loop to me, that's like PHP 101.  Maybe `NULL` will kill it? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php When there is no more rows to read.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix: Yes, the *original* code is a database result. But OP question says that the code was *changed* to use a hardcoded array instead. In the modified code (which seems to be what OP asked about), `$product_countries` is no longer a resultset from a database query (that assignment is commented out). The following line assigns an array to that variable. And then OP is showing a `while` loop that assigns the array to another variable, **`while ($listing_details = $product_details)`**. I'm not seeing any condition that exits the while loop.

Comment: Ok, I see that now thanks for clearing it up.   Sorry about the mix up.  Re reading what I put it looks a bit harsh, didn;t mean it that I just wondered how someone with 46k could miss that.  So again thanks for clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT country
FROM db_products
```

should be able to make good use of an index on `db_products(country)`.

Second, you should have a separate table of countries, with `db_products` containing a `countryId`, referring to the other table.  If you had that, then displaying the list of countries would be a no-brainer.

Answer (score 0):

AS I stated in the comments, the better way to do this is have a list of countries in a separate table, and reference them in your product table.

This is called normalization, generally you should think of it like this.  A product is a thing with certain attributes of which country is only one, it might have a price, or a SKU number for example..

Countries too are a thing, they may have abbreviations, shipping codes, laws that deal with this or that, many things.  They are not as simple as say a SKU number or a price.  But, could contain other useful data unrelated to a specific product, don't they deserve a table all their own?

It's hard to say the structure of this table or the relationship between a product and a country without knowing more.  But, you may be able to eliminate a lot of redundant data.  Ask yourself these two things:

- Can a product have more then one country?
- Can a country supply more then one product?

Those will tell you the relationship you need.